# Why i cannot getting correct Fourier transformed image using matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, fft

I am trying a test some Fourier transformation operations, but i cannot get correct Fourier transformed image, for example, consider following images:

[image: Lenna][image][image: What is suppose to be]

The last image is the Fourier transformed image what which should be my output

The matlab code i have used is as following:

```
function fftshow(file)
    close all;
    img=imread(file);
    ft=fft2(img(:,:,1));
    sft=fftshift(ft);
    asft = abs(sft);
    lasft = log2(asft+1);
    imagesc(img), title('The real image');
    pause
    imagesc(asft), colormap([0,0,0;1,1,1]), title('The magnitude image');
    pause
    imagesc(lasft), colormap([0,0,0;1,1,1]), title('The log2 magnitude image');
    clear img ft sft;
end
```

what am i doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why not just try imshow(lasft,[])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`colormap([0,0,0;1,1,1])` works as a binary display, use `colormap(gray)` instead.